# Run Jenkins build when git commit is done

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I know that this question is posted in different topic.But my case is a little bit different.

I want to trigger my test goal when a commit is detected by Jenkins. Most tutorials in the internet show how to do this using WebHook.

In my case I have two problems :

1) I did not find the option "Trigger build when a commit is detected"

[image]

2) All tutorials speak about configuring webhook, from Git URL.in my case, my git repository is local and I did not have access to the web interface. So how to do the same thing manually ?

Thank ou in advance

**Configuration :**

- Jenkins Server 1.651.1
- Git Plugin 2.4.4,

Comment: If your repository is local, how is Jenkins checking out the new version for building? Normally you would configure a git hook on the server to notify Jenkins that a push has occurred and it should check for anything of interest. If you only have a local repository you would have to do that on commits - so the post-commit.hook. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks for some information on git hooks.

Comment: Jenkins and Git repo are in the same machine :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3S2gMBUkBo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it in a little bit different way:

You do use a web-hook to capture when new git commit was made and in the hook you start the Jenkins job with the rest API.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Read all about it in here:

http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reponse. I will give it a try. But this is not responding to my first question. Why in Jenkins jobs I coulnd't found the option "Trigger build when a commit is detected"" ??

Comment: Do you use a pull job? Jenkins automatically will start a build if its a pull job.

Comment: I have configured a pull job, but since the url of git repo is local one to Jenkins server, It shown a message No git jobs using repository: \\msxxxx\Git-repositories$\test.git and branches. No Git consumers using SCM API plugin for  \\msxxxx\Git-repositories$\test.git. Maye be should I write it in a different way ?

Comment: Done :) it works know. Thank ou for your help ;) I just changed to //msxxxx/Git-repositories$/test.git