# How to separate libraries and code in different jar files

Tags: java, jar, libraries

I have a java code including 5 classes which is my code and it depends on 5 other libraries that I've downloaded from maven. now I want to put them in my VPS and test it from there and I need to modify my code there but I don't want to modify it in my personal computer and put it in a jar file and send it to server over and over again. I just might need to test a few different options and make minor changes in one of the classes. how can I do this? the best option that comes to my mind is if I can have all of my libraries put together in one jar and then I put the class files of my codes in my server in the same parent directory of the jar file and edit them and then compile them with javac and run the java output main.java file in a way that it can use the other 4 .java files in the directory and the one jar file that includes the libraries.
So how can I do this. I searched everywhere and I'm just so confused now.
By the way my server is ubuntu 16.4.

Comment: The solution is to test on your local development machine until you're happy, and then only make a release and upload the jar files on your server.

Comment: Use something like jenkins: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936521/run-jenkins-build-when-git-commit-is-done

Comment: But I'm using mongodb and I don't have mongodb on my laptop and also my laptop is windows. But my VPS in ubuntu.@JBNizet

Comment: Then install MongoDB on your laptop. Or (but I wouldn't recommend it) access the MongoDB instance located on your server from your laptop. Java is portable, so the fact that the server is running ubuntu and your laptop is running windows doesn't matter.

Comment: Why don't you recommend that? And actually I tried to do that but I couldn't and actually I have a question about that here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041607/how-to-remotely-connect-to-my-mongodb-in-my-server-with-java?noredirect=1#comment79070576_46041607 But also the code is different when you are doing it remotely or locally.@JBNizet

Comment: You could also build all your options locally and trigger them via args on your server. This way there would be no need to seperate local from server code.

Comment: Simply because it would make things harder than necessary.

Comment: I don't want to separate local and server code. All the code is on server. I just want to modify the code on server. with ssh. @rndus2r